# How can I draw on one Label with multiple classes? (Java)

Tags: java, swing, draw, jlabel

I am currently programming a game which includes lots of graphical elements. Currently the code looks like this:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g.drawImage(ImageLoader.gui_iconbar, xToRel(480), yToRel(810), xToRel(960), yToRel(270), null);
        g.drawImage(ClientVariables.getSplashart(Main.selectedCharacter, 0), xToRel(495), yToRel(825), xToRel(135), yToRel(240), null);

        //... (don't get confused with xToRel, it just makes changes to the drawing position if you move the camera)
}
```

The problem is: there are TONS of these `g.draw(whatever);` lines. I want to split them in multiple classes but just making 4 classes and copy paste gameFrame.add(GraphicclassXY); doesn't work, logically. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? (It's not a problem if the solution includes making changes from jlabel to canvas for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create logical non-component classes (that don't extend JLabel, JPanel, JFrame, JComponent or other Swing component), give them a `public void draw(Graphics g)` method, give the class that *does* the drawing instances of your logical classes, perhaps within some sort of collection, and iterate through the collection and call `draw` on your instances within the paintComponent method.